# Programmatically navigate to a dynamic url with gatsby

Tags: reactjs, routes, gatsby

I am using navigate to move to another URL. I saw many posts using `Link` to move to another page with dynamic url. But I want to change url without writing `jsx`

When I navigate to the following url, I get a 404 error

```
navigate(`/vidx/${u}`, {
      state: { vid: r }
    })
```

I changed gatsby-node.js to following, still getting the same error. I have a file named `vidx.js` in `pages` folder

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {   
    const { createPage } = actions
    if (page.path.match(/^\/vidx/)) {
      page.matchPath = "/vidx/*";
      createPage(page); 
    } 
}
```

My url will look like this - `www.xyz.com/vidx/123456789`. The number `123456789` will depend upon the user logged in

Comment: is the `vidx/123456789` path existing?

Comment: No. This number is dynamically generated, whenever a new user signup

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. You are trying to redirect to a non-created page?

Comment: I want to redirect to `vidx.js`; but the URL should be `/vidx/123456789`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to redirect to vidx.js; but the URL should be /vidx/123456789

That will never work since `/vidx/123456789` will always throw a `404` error since it's not generated and doesn't exist, it's a separate new page.

One easy thing you can do use: `/vidx?queryParameter=123456789`. In that case, your page will remain being `/vidx` and you can get the `queryParameter` to make your stuff with your own logic.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the url to `http://localhost:8000/vidx/?v=1613907113203`. I have a vidx.js in pages folder. But still I am getting `Create a React.js component in your site directory at src/pages/vidx.jsand this page will automatically refresh to show the new page component you created.`

Comment: Can you share the code of the vidx.js page?

Comment: Here- https://codepen.io/shrwtz/pen/jOVLgpK?editors=0010

Comment: Hey, working now. I did `gatsby clean`. Thanks a lot!